# Difference between .query() and .execute() in MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, syntax-error

I'm having difficulty comprehending the implementation of prepared statements. I've done a fair amount of research but most of the information I found is either out of context or contain examples far more complex than what I'm trying to accomplish. Can anyone clarify for me why the execute method in the second example below is throwing a syntax error?

NOTE: I'm using the node-mysql2 package here.

controller.js  (using *query* mysql method)

```
  const db = require("../lib/database");


  async addNewThing(req, res, next) {

    let data = req.body

    const queryString = 'INSERT INTO table SET ?'
    try {
      await db.query(queryString, data)
      res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Record inserted',
        data
      })
    } catch (error) {
      next(error)
    }
  }
```

Record is successfully inserted into the database

---

controller.js    (using *execute* mysql method)

```
  const db = require("../lib/database");


  async addNewThing(req, res, next) {

    let data = req.body

    const queryString = 'INSERT INTO table SET ?'
    try {
      await db.execute(queryString, [data])
      res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Record inserted',
        data
      })
    } catch (error) {
      next(error)
    }
  }
```

Results in the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '?' at line 1

---

data

```
{ thing_id: '987654', thing_name: 'thing' }
```

Comment: Can you share an example of the `data` you're passing to the query?

Comment: @Mureinik Sure, see above.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With `.query()`, parameter substitution is handled on the client, including objects which `let data = req.body` is in the above examples.

With `.execute()` prepared statement parameters are sent from the client as a serialized string and handled by the server. Since `let data = req.body` is an object, that's not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to pass dynamically changing inputs as parameters and not by string concatenation. This example might help.

Query - `SELECT * from users where users.id = ? LIMIT ?` Params - `[1,10]`

*.query()* - `SELECT * from users where users.id = 1 LIMIT 10` ✅

*.execute()* - `SELECT * from users where users.id = 1 LIMIT ?` ❌

So in this case, *.execute()* will throw an error code: 'ER_WRONG_ARGUMENTS', as the limit's value has to be part of the query and cannot be passed as input params later.